# PHP: Rounding Numbers are not reconciled as numbers?

Tags: php, numbers, rounding, equals

When I round a number, it does not appear to be read as a number anymore.

```
$numberVar = 3.2;

$numberVar = round($numberVar);

if ($numberVar === 3) {
    echo 'true';
}

else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: `round()` returns a *double*, not an integer.

Comment: `round` returns a `double`, `3` is an `int` - they are _not_ strictly equal (`===`) but they _are_ equal (`==`)